# Broken plugin dependancy on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is my list of plugins for jenkins:

```
InstallPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.3.1
    - workflow-aggregator:2.7.3
    - workflow-job:2.17
    - workflow-cps:2.45
    - credentials-binding
    - git
    - git-client:2.7.1
    - ghprb
    - github-oauth:0.29
    - repository-connector
    - credentials
    - ssh-credentials
    - pipeline-github-lib
    - github
    - aws-credentials
    - amazon-ecr
    - swarm
    - ws-cleanup
    - aws-bucket-credentials
    - ssh-agent:1.15
    - ant:1.8
    - gradle
    - rebuild
    - pipeline-model-definition
    - delivery-pipeline-plugin
    - build-pipeline-plugin
    - workflow-multibranch
    - jobConfigHistory
    - pipeline-model-extensions
    - pipeline-rest-api
    - job-dsl
    - hashicorp-vault-plugin
```

I am getting a failure in the logs:

```
2020-09-04 14:22:52.145+0000 [id=32]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Multibranch v2.22 (workflow-multibranch)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Multibranch (2.22)
 - Update required: Pipeline: Job (2.36) to be updated to 2.39 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:934)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:548)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-09-04 14:22:52.174+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline SCM API for Blue Ocean v1.23.2 (blueocean-pipeline-scm-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline SCM API for Blue Ocean (1.23.2)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Multibranch (2.22)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:934)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:548)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can I check which plugin has which dependency? I am not experienced in Jenkins, so I am not sure where to find a definition of dependency in the plugin's git repositories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer and groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864983/598141) to [How to list all available jenkins plugins using command list with their short names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56852925/598141) .

Note: your list should only specify top-level plugins(unless absolutely necessary); let the dependency resolution do its job for the rest.

On the `${JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager,` if you hover on the uninstall, it should show depedant plugins, but you have to have Jenkins running for that.