# Jenkins - list top level plugins on existing master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

All the examples of listing plugins on existing jenkins master I was able to find produce full list of installed plugins (e.g. top level + dependencies + deps of deps and so on).

Is there a way to list only the top level plugins?

Comment: If there are no dependencies listed, it's a top-level plugin.

Comment: Depends how you look at it. By top level I mean those who has dependencies but no other plugin depends on them.
In other words, 
I'm looking for a minimal list of plugins if used in plugins.txt(which resolves deps) it will install all the plugins as original master.

Comment: There is no definitive answer; it is all installation dependant. "Git-plugin" could be a "top-level" plugin, unless you use "github-plugin" or "tfs-plugin", in which case it's not. What if you use pipeline (workflow) or blue-ocean? Refer to the scripts in  [my prior response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864983/598141) and figure out your particular circumstance.