# Jenkins failed to install plugins in startup

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to install Jenkins on win 10.
all the plugins failed to install on the startup process and even after that for jenkins GUI.
i'm running with jenkins 2.264,jdk-8u271-windows-x64 and windows 10 pro.
please advise what am I doing worng.

this is one of my error messages ->
most of the errors look the same. (Java issue)

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Build Timeout (1.20)
 - Plugin is missing: token-macro (1.5.1)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:951)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:551)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1129)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2020-12-24 18:52:29.987+0000 [id=46]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin ECharts API Plugin v4.9.0-2 (echarts-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: ECharts API Plugin (4.9.0-2)
```

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: Any proxies running behind ?

Comment: @user12755014, if you found [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448203/598141) helpful, consider upvote. If it answered your question, also mark as answered (and delete your explanative answer). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is an incomplete pair of error segments (they should start w/timestamp). Nevertheless, not sure how you installed the plugins, but you appear to be missing some key dependencies.

```
 Failed to load: Build Timeout (1.20)  - Plugin is missing: token-macro (1.5.1)
```

[**token-macro**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/) is a dependency on [**Build Timeout**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timeout/#dependencies), and appears not to installed.

```
 Failed to load: ECharts API Plugin (4.9.0-2)
```

This error is incomplete, but I would suspect is also missing a dependency. You can see what is installed on the `${JENKINS_URL}/systemInfo` page, "**Plugins**" section. Not sure what you will see on the `${JENKINS_URL}/pluginManager/installed`, but I suspect many plugins will be greyed out. It should explain why (ie: missing).

You would have to explain how you installed what you did to guess how got are missed. Rarely plugins simply declare as "optional" what should be declared as required, but goes undetected since almost everyone always installs the dependency.

Usually, they all point to a single missing plugin or a chain up from one. Check the logs and trace. Get all the pairs `Failed to load: x  - Plugin is missing: y`. Install the ones said to be missing. Failing that, stop Jenkins, delete the `/plugins` directory and install them from scratch again. If the `hpi/jpi` package is corrupted, you may need to stop Jenkins, delete the package and the exploded directory inside `plugins`.

You may also find [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864983/598141) useful, as well as the Jenkins Book [Managing Plugins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/) and the new [Plugin Installation Manager Tool for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool)