# How to check for newer Jenkins plugin versions automatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are using the official Jenkins docker image to run [Jenkins serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/building-a-serverless-jenkins-environment-on-aws-fargate/). The docker image contains a [install-plugins.sh script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh) that can be fed with a list of plugins and their versions, and is run during the image build.

Although Jenkins warns about outdated plugins in the admin backend, is there any way to update that list (format) easily?

The plugin list format looks like

```
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.13-1.0
authentication-tokens:1.3
aws-credentials:1.28
(...)
credentials:2.3.7
git-client:3.2.1
git-server:1.9
git:4.8.1
```

and I was hoping for a cli tool or online tool to hand in that list and get info about newer plugin versions and bring them to the newest version easily. Apparently, the Jenkins plugins repository provides this information per plugin at, e.g., https://plugins.jenkins.io/apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api/#releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Plugin Installation Manager Tool](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool) will replace a wide range of plugin management tools attempts, and as stated in the Jenkins docker image repository readme, the [install-plugins.sh script is deprecated](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#install-plugins-script-deprecated).

> I was hoping for a cli tool or online tool to hand in that list and
> get info about newer plugin versions and bring them to the newest
> version easily

With Plugin Installation Manager Tool, it's as easy as feeding your existing list into the tool using:

`--available-updates:` (optional) Set to true to show if any requested plugins have newer versions available. If a Jenkins version-specific update center is available, the latest plugin version will be determined based on that update center's data.

The [readme file has an example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#updating-plugins-file-preview) how to call it. Remember to specify your plugins-list file as input.

Other helpful options:
`--no-download`: (optional) Set to true to not download plugins. By default it is set to false and plugins will be downloaded.
`--latest false:` (optional) Set to false to download the minimum required version of all dependencies.
`--latest-specified`: (optional) (advanced) Set to true to download latest dependencies of any plugin that is requested to have the latest version. All other plugin dependency versions are determined by the update center metadata or the plugin MANIFEST.MF.

---

**Additional notes:**

Both `install_plugins.sh` and **Plugin Installation Manager Tool** will **accept just the pluginname** (no version) or pluginname:latest, which will retrieve the latest version available when run. See [detailed examples](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool#examples).

Both tools will also **automatically download dependencies** if only the required base plugin is specified. *ie: git includes git-client, apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api, credentials, but not aws-credentials (but aws-credentials includes credentials)*.

The risk is changes in plugin versions can dependencies may add versions or plugins you are not aware of (or you keep obsolete/redundant dependencies). Or there's just a newer dependency. But that can work either way.

It's always good to save the summary of what is downloaded ; you can [generate a "complete list"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864983/598141) for reference. Our best practice is to use a SPEC list of required plugins to generate a current complete plugin off-line. Both lists are checked into VCS, along with [CasC yaml files](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin#readme) for each plugin. Use the complete list w/exact version in the instance configuration. Use the SPEC list to consider feature upgrades and the complete list for security issues.

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you very much for your answer. I took the liberty to make it shorter and hope it is ok for you. I removed your comment regarding specifying-specific-versions in the plugins file vs always downloading the latest version. Coming from other dependency managers, controlling the exact version is very important to replicate environments and have reliability. So I took this for granted and removed the general remark. Hope it is alright for you. Thanks again.

Comment: Saw your edits. I obviously don't proofread my answers well! It's important to acknowledge the option for "latest" and also the implicit dependency download as they can change and may download extras on you.  It's easier to keep track of what you "need" and monitor that for features vs what's installed (for security). Those options provide a complete answer for others with a similar scenario but may always just want latest (25 years in Config Mgmt, I know it's a bad idea, but some like that option).

Comment: When setting up a new instance at "Giant Corp", we feed the list of required plugins (SPEC) and get latest (for the LTS release). We review the entire downloaded list for compliance, then check both the SPEC list and the derived list into the instance CasC VCS. Replicas will get the same derived list. Upgrading works from the SPEC'd list.. We have a staging instance to set things up and many live instances meeting different userbase needs. Each plugin gets a separate yaml config file in the [CasC configuration](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin#readme).

Comment: Hopefully reads useful for all now as reformatted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235971/discussion-between-richard-kiefer-and-ian-w).

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose Plugin Installation Manager Tool exists.

Check the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrttfNgB1hk) how to use it

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, I appreciate you pointing me to this plugin very much. It helped me in solving my use case. But I want to encourage you to elaborate a bit more on your suggestion. I think in its current form, it serves better as a comment than an answer.