# How to check Specific plugin of dependency plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

How can I list the plugins and dependencies plugin?
Which plugins depend on which ones?
Example:
Pipeline Plugin of all dependent plugin ("pipeline-build-step";"pipeline-raph-analysis";"pipeline-input-step";....)also install automatic

Comment: This [script will list all the plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56864983/598141). [Dependencies tab](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-build-step/#dependencies) of each plugin lists all the direct dependencies and dependants. Installing a plugin you want will install its dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list all available jenkins plugins using command list with their short names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852925/how-to-list-all-available-jenkins-plugins-using-command-list-with-their-short-na)